# AJAX on multiple views pagers fails to work

Tags: 7, views, blocks, ajax, paging

I have a situation that not all of my AJAX enabled pagers are working.

- I have several blocks on a page where each block is a view with a pager.
- Each pager has a unique ID.
- I use Context to determine which blocks to show on the page.
- Some blocks will consistently work, but other ignore AJAX and instead go for a full page refresh.
- And most importantly, it only fails for anonymous users. It works consistently when I am logged in as an administrator.

How can I ensure that the AJAX pager will work consistently?

Comment: Have you looked at the console.log after interacting with the various pagers?

Comment: Yes. No error messages or anything of note when it works and when it doesn't.

Comment: There's some discussion of this here https://drupal.org/node/2156119